# Lock to CSV cell in VB script

Tags: csv, vbscript

I created a following CSV file in VB script.

```
Set CSVFile = FS.OpenTextFile(Server.MapPath(FilePath),2,True)

CSVFile.WriteLine "Name, English, Math"
CSVFile.WriteLine "Aung Aung, 100, 90"
CSVFile.WriteLine "Ko Ko, 80, 60"

Name       English            Math
Aung Aung  100                90
Ko Ko      80                 60
```

In this case, I want to lock the some cell (Name, English, Math, Aung Aung, Ko Ko). Other cells should still be editable. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I'm aware you can't lock cells in a CSV file.  Cell locking is a meta-data option only available in a spreadsheet (such as Excel).  If you're using VBScript there are [script options for manipulating Excel spreadsheets](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/scripts/msoffice/excel/) instead.

If, on the other hand, you're talking about continuing to use this script to read user input and writing it out to the CSV file, then you can simply refuse to update certain column positions if you want them locked.